# jQuery, is there a way to encodeURIComponent a FormData?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm converting a form submission into an ajax submission with this script:

```
var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ...myurl...
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
            ...some success code
            }
```

The script is working fine except for characters like ò à è that are wrongly encoded turning into strange characters.
I think I need to use the **encodeURIComponent** function but I don't know how and if it's possible on FormData.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: please check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuricomponent

Comment: data: { name: encodeURIComponent(name) }

Comment: Thanks Osgux, but it doesn't work for me, the solution you suggests is valid if you know the field name to encode. My needs are to use a generic script to use with different form with different input names, that's the reason I'm using FormData to read input fields

Answer (score 0):

Some references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
  <label>Your email address:</label>
  <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" size="32" maxlength="64" /><br />
  <label>Custom file label:</label>
  <input type="text" name="filelabel" size="12" maxlength="32" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>

var formTest = document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo");
formTest.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

var oData = new FormData(formTest);
var newForm = new FormData();
for(var pair of oData.entries()) {
   newForm.append(pair[0],encodeURIComponent(pair[1])); 
}

for(var test of newForm.entries()) {
   alert(test[0]+ ', '+ test[1]); 
}

ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s35dg34b/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's serialize method. It serializes and encodes the whole form.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ...myurl...
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
        ...some success code
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution I thought about, but I also have to transfer files so that way won't work for me.
I've meanwhile found the solution, I will post asap.